# Split string with emoji

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, emoji

I need to split `QString` in array of all characters. It can contain `emoji`.
QString:      
After `string.split("")`:

```
""
"?"
"?"
" "
"?"
"?"
" "
"?"
"?"
" "
" "
"?"
"?"
" "
"?"
"?"
" "
"?"
"?"
""
```

I understand, that emoji can take more that 1 byte, but how can i split my string then? Thanks.

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: I dont understood you.. It is Qt.

Comment: Qt is a library. With bindings for multiple languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, QString does not support unicode characters greater than U+FFFF. In this test script you can see that it fails to calculate string size correctly for those characters:

```
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QList<QByteArray> list;
    list << QByteArray("a");
    list << QByteArray("ö");
    list << QByteArray("➜");
    list << QByteArray("☀");
    list << QByteArray("⚡");
    list << QByteArray("");
    list << QByteArray("");
    list << QByteArray("");

    foreach (QByteArray binary, list)
    {
        QString str = QString::fromUtf8(binary);
        qDebug() << str;
        qDebug() << "Bytes:" << binary.size();
        qDebug() << "String size:" << str.size();
        {
            QDebug debugLine = (qDebug() << "Unicode code point:");
            for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
            {
                debugLine << str[i].unicode();
            }
        }
        qDebug() << "";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
"a"
Bytes: 1
String size: 1
Unicode code point: 97

"ö"
Bytes: 2
String size: 1
Unicode code point: 246

"➜"
Bytes: 3
String size: 1
Unicode code point: 10140

"☀"
Bytes: 3
String size: 1
Unicode code point: 9728

"⚡"
Bytes: 3
String size: 1
Unicode code point: 9889

""
Bytes: 4
String size: 2
Unicode code point: 55357 56832

""
Bytes: 4
String size: 2
Unicode code point: 55357 57030

""
Bytes: 4
String size: 2
Unicode code point: 55357 56373
```

Comment: So.. It is no way to split string and put characters in QList?

Comment: I don't see one with QString at the moment. But I cannot guarantee my research covers the topic entirely.